# function loadHTMLString from UIWebView costs too much memory

Tags: ios, memory, uiwebview

The function `loadHTMLString` from UIWebView costs too much memory and will activate the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` of the current UIViewController.

How do I solve it please :D

Comment: I have the same issue , do you solve it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it might be that your html NSString for loadHTMLString: too long, which I mean that the NSString's size for loadHTMLString: is too large. And if you have some image url in your html string, it might have problem,too.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing your HTML in a file and then:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Thanks, but the htmlString is from web, write the string to file is not a good solution

Comment: From web? Why not load it using just URLRequest?

Answer (score 0):

if you use webview only to load one html page

i think you should optimize your page th solve it

if you load many pages  you should clean the webview before you load another or dealloc

like this

```
[webView loadHTMLString: @"" baseURL: nil];
```

Comment: for strange reason, this is exactly what I've done to save me from memory leak inside uiwebview... Remember to let the webview time to load this empty string (so that the cleanup happens).